# How can the Blender API be used to access Blender from another application?

Tags: python, external-applications

Take Openshot for example. It has some form of Blender integration and is written in Python.

I'm not sure if it directly accesses Blender's API or if it simply generates a `.blend` file and then launches Blender (as it seems to do with Inkscape for SVG titles).

What I would like to know is:

1. Can an application make use of the Blender API from outside of a running instance of Blender?
2. If yes, how?

Comment: Doesn't the OpenShot site say that it is built on Blender? Not that it's integrated.

Comment: I've used Openshot, and read the website, and I don't get that impression. As far as I understand it *uses* Blender to generate animated titles, but is not *built on* Blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around a little bet [here's what I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136852/running-blender-python-script-outside-of-blender). You can render files outside of Blender(from the terminal), but as far as I can tell, you cannot do anything else.

Answer (score 5):

Following the link in CharlesL's answer, I was able to find a Wiki entry that dashes my hopes. Apparently this is not possible in the way I had hoped.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule

Comment: bpy-as-module is actually quite powerful. It's a very clean way to call the Blender API within a pure Python environment. You *can* use it to generate a .blend file without ever touching Blender.

Comment: You said the entry dashes your hopes. Just curious, how were you hoping to be able to use it? Were you looking for a way to 'remote control' blender from an external python process?

Comment: @greatwolf something like that.